# Unable to switch to MainActivity after data insertion from repository in MVVM architecture

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I am implementing MVVM architecture pattern for app development.I have two activities **MainActivity** and **AddUser** activity.In **MainActivity** I am showing list of all notes and in **AddUser** activity I am inserting user in **room** database.I am doing all insertion and fetching notes operation in repository class.I am using **RxJava Completable** operator to insert notes in database.

**What I want:** After insertion it should redirect to the MainActivity.

**Problem:** Unable to add Intent in onComplete() method when I am using Intent it is showing error.

**Error**

```
Process: com.app.notesreactive, PID: 3970
io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with.
```

Below is my code:

**UserDao.java**

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {

@Insert
void insert(User user);

@Query("SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY id DESC")
LiveData<List<User>> getAllUsers();

}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
public class UserRepository {

private UserDb userDb;
private UserDao userDao;
private LiveData<List<User>> allUsers;
private Context ctx;

public UserRepository(Application application) {

    userDb = UserDb.getInstance(application);
    userDao = userDb.userDao();
    allUsers = userDao.getAllUsers();
    ctx = application.getApplicationContext();
}

public void insert(final User user){

   Completable.fromAction(() -> userDb.userDao().insert(user))
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete() {

                                         Intent i = new Intent(ctx,MainActivity.class);
                                        ctx.startActivity(i);

                                        Toast.makeText(ctx,"Data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                                       Toast.makeText(ctx,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });

      }

   public LiveData<List<User>> getAllUsers(){

       return allUsers;
    }

  }
```

Someone please help me out how can I achieve desired result.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: You are not following proper MVVM architecture. Try calling methods of repository from viewmodel and notify using live data to views (Activity).

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Yes I am calling methods using ViewModel and updating UI's from viewModel.

Comment: Use subscribe and observe in viewmodel not in repository class.

Comment: I have updated my post aand after modifying onComplete() method it is showing error posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching the activity from repository class we need to add the following flags to the Intent.
Here is an updated onComplete() method.

```
@Override
public void onComplete() {

      Intent i = new Intent(ctx,MainActivity.class);
      i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
      ctx.startActivity(i);

      Toast.makeText(ctx,"Data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Hopefully it will help.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 1):

Staring an activity in a repository is not good practice. You need to start an activity within an activity. If you want to start activity with application *Context* you should use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. Cause starting an activity from application's `Context` with *default flags* brakes the *back stack* of activities (hierarchy). I suggest to use *observables* like RxJava's `Observable` or `LiveData` from [AAC](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture) to notify the activity, and start another activity on it. How to do it with `LivaData`?

Updated `insert` method as following:

```
public LiveData<Boolean> insert(final User user){
    MutableLiveData<Boolean> isComplated = new MutableLiveData<>();

    Completable.fromAction(() -> userDb.userDao().insert(user))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                isComplated.setValue(true);
                Toast.makeText(ctx,"Data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    return isComplated;
}
```

Observe this in `AddUser` activity class:

```
viewModel.insert(myUser).observe(this, isComplated -> {
    if (isComplated != null && isComplated) {
        Intent i = new Intent(AddUser.this, MainActivity.class);
        ctx.startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

**Edit:**
The ViewModel class should contain following method:

```
public LiveData<Boolean> insert(User user) {
    return userRepositoryInstance.insert(user);
}
```

It should help =)

Comment: Do I need to update Dao insert method because I have void insert(User user).

Comment: No need to do that @Digvijay

Comment: is there anything wrong with my answer please let me know because it is working fine.

Comment: There is nothing wrong. But it is wrong from view of MVVM architecture. It is not repository's responsibility to do view manipulations.

Comment: I am implementing your solution but in my add user view model class it is saying Unable to resolve observe.

Comment: `observe` is `LiveData`'s member method. Make sure that you are getting `LivaData`. Also I have edited my answer for more details. Pleas check it =) @Digvijay